# MVVM Nested Binding on GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, autocomplete

I have a Viewmodel that contains property named Projects and **Users**. The Project class contains Project Manager, Date, AssignedTo properties. In my view I have a Grid where my itemsource is bound to Projects and have datacolumns bounded to Project Manager, Date and Assigned To.

Now I added a cell edit template to AssignedTo column by adding an autocomplete textbox so when the user edits that column it will give auto suggested User values. My problem now is that I am wanting that the ItemSource of this autocomplete textbox to be bound to the property of my ViewModel which is **Users**(which is a list of string). Since the grid is already bounded to the Project how can I force the celledit template to bind into the other property in my ViewModel which is the **Users**.

I understand that there are some ways to do this such as attaching another presentation property to Projects but I do not want to do that as this class is used a lot in my application. I did try different types of bindings e.g. relativesource but nothing seems to work fine at this stage. Maybe I am missing something or really there is no way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best method I've seen is to use what's called a "[data context proxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx)".  Put it in the resources section of the XAML doc, like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Now you can bind to it as a static resource, from your auto-complete collection, for example:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyViewModel.AutoCompleteItems,Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"
```

(Note that you have to prefix the path with `DataContext` to get the right binding.)

I don't quite understand why the *RelativeSource* binding doesn't work in these cases, but I've had similar trouble when trying to bind from inside a Data Grid.  This data context proxy method is easy to use, though, and does the job.

Comment: hi, sorry it took me a while to reply. Apparrently we didnt go on this direction. I appreciate you giving answer though.